# How do you turn a servo 90 degrees when you press a button and do the same with 180 degrees and 0 degrees

Tags: c++, arduino

it  maybe looks like a dumb quistion but im still in my learning process and im really trying to look on the internet but sometimes i don't really get it to make it work.
my code is as followed:

> ```
> #include <Arduino.h>
> #include <Servo.h>
>
> Servo Myservo;
> int SERVO_PIN = 8;
> int ServoButton_S1 = 2;
>
> void setup() {
>   Myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);
> }
>
> void loop() {
>   Myservo.write(0);
>   delay(2000);
>   Myservo.write(90);
>   delay(2000);
>   Myservo.write(180);
>   delay(2000);
> }
> ```

The servo now goes from 0 degrees (wait 2 sec) and than goes to 90 degrees (wait 2 sec) and goes to 180 degrees and so it continious.

The problem is that i want a servo that moves whenever i press the button.
so its like when i press the button the servo goes to 90 degrees but when i press the button again it goes to 180 degrees and when i push it again to 0 degrees and so it has to continue.
so i added the button and i called it:

> int servobutton_s1 = 2;

but whenever i added it in the void loop it only works 1 time.

i hope someone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: where is the button handling code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the button state for every loop iteration.
Something like:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Servo.h>

Servo Myservo;
int SERVO_PIN = 8;
const int ServoButton_S1 = 2;
int some_counter = 0;

void setup() {
  Myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);
}

void loop() 
{
  //read the state of the pushbutton value:
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed. If it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    if (some_counter == 0)
    {
        Myservo.write(0);
        delay(2000);
        ++some_counter;
    }
    else if (some_counter == 1)
    {
        Myservo.write(90);
        delay(2000);
        ++some_counter;
    } 
    else if (some_counter == 2)
    {
        Myservo.write(180);
        delay(2000);
        some_counter = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

You can also check the Arduino website; there are a lot of tutorial examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another solution.

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>

#define SERVO_PIN 8
#define ANGLE_BUTTON 2

Servo Myservo;
int counter = 0;
int angles[] = {0, 90, 180};
int angleAmounts = sizeof(angles) / sizeof(angles[0]);

void setup() {
  pinMode(ANGLE_BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);
}

void loop()
{
  int buttonState = digitalRead(ANGLE_BUTTON);

  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    counter = ++counter % angleAmounts;
    Myservo.write(angles[counter]);
    delay(2000);
  }
}
```